# Better logs and tracking bottlenecks in heroku

Tags: python, django, logging, heroku

I have a backend server running on heroku. Right now for going through logs all I have been using is the 'heroku logs' command. I have been using that command also to track how long different requests to each endpoint are taking.

Is there a better way to see a list of how long requests to different endpoints are taking and a good way to track bottlenecks for what is slowing down these endpoints? Also is there any good add ons for heroku that can point out bad responses that are not status =200?

I am using python with django if that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best tool I found is newrelic.com It hooks nicely into django apps and heroku. It can even show you the bottlenecks due to queries and functions inside your views.